# flex data provider not working if XML has single node value or less

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, dataprovider

i get this error when i retrieve an XML that only has 1 node (no repeating nodes) and i try to store in an ArrayCollection. -When I have MORE than 1 "name" nodes...i do NOT get an error.  My test show that XMLListCollection does NOT work either.

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "XXXXXX" to mx.collections.ArrayCollection.
```

this error occurs as the line of code:

```
myList= e.result.list.name;
```

Why can't ArrayCollection work with a single node? I'm using this ArrayCollection as a dataprovider for a Component -is there an alternative I can use that will take BOTH single and repeating nodes as well as work as a dataprovider?  Thanks in advance!

code:

```
[Bindable]
private var myList:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection();

        private function getList(e:Event):void{

            var getStudyLoungesService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
            getStuffService.url = "website.com/asdf.php";
            getStuffService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onGetList);
            getStuffService.send();

        }

        private function onGetList(e:ResultEvent):void{

            myList= e.result.list.name;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is, that if you only have one row Flex will complain since it cannot use the result as arrayCollection.

My work around was, that you put number of rows into your XML with the data you want to return:
for example I did:

```
<list><nr_rows>3</nr_rows><name>...</name><name>...</name><name>...</name></list>
```

So when I get the result back I do a check of how many rows I am getting with (You can get the number of rows returned from MySQL query with `mysql_num_rows`)

```
e.result.list.nr_rows
```

So if this is one, you add Object to the arrayCollection, if there are more than one you can just use result and equal it to AC (in this case projects is AC):

```
if (event.result.list.nr_rows == '1'){
    myList.addItem(event.result.list.name);
} else {
    myList = event.result.list.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particular about getting the final result onto a ArrayCollection, you can do the following to get the final result onto an XMLList or XMLListCollection.

1) set the resultFormat property of HTTPService to e4x.

2) Do not mention the root xml tag name while referencing it.  Reference the output as: myList:XMLList = e.result.name.

This works whether the retrieved XML has one or more than one elements.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem today and it led me to this question.  I'm not sure if your use-case is exactly the same as mine, but you might want to try `showRoot="true"` on the mx:Tree.  It seems to force the root node to be shown when there is only one item, and gets ignored with multiple items.

Answer (score -1):

add a row object to get the row of the XML node can work, but I think some better method have be, is ActionScript is as powerful as Java?